# How can i set full page size textbox ( like notepad ) with tkinter python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to set a full page size textbox with tkinter in python. I want to do this because if the program run with full page textbox, i can write value from rfid automatically. Otherwise i have to click the page if i want to write value with rfid reader.

def onReturn(event):

```
            rfIDtext=entry1.get()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO RFIDDATA(customer_ID,rf_ID) VALUES (?,?)",(custID,rfIDtext,))


            entry1.delete(0,'end')
            root.destroy()
            con.commit()   
            
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("RFID")
        
        entry1 =tk.Entry(root)
        entry1.bind("<Return>",onReturn)
        entry1.pack(pady=20)
        root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) # that is program size not textbox
        
        root.mainloop()
                
        con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `tk.Text`. It has `-height` and `-width` options. You can use `root.width()` for the window's width and `root.height()` for the window's height.

```py
text = tk.Text(root, width = root.width(), height = root.height())
text.pack(pady=20)
```

EDIT: To focus the entry/text you should use `entry1.focus()`.

Comment: Actually, basically i want to take a value from rfid automatically, when i run the code. But my problem is when my program run, i have to click the text box for write something. Exactly this is my main problem.

Comment: @coding_witherrors I am not sure but I think you can use `entry1.focus()`. I need to research.

Comment: @coding_witherrors I tried `entry1.focus()` in my editor and it seemed to work, so I will update my answer to include that.